# Allow only one algo trade at a time - python

Tags: python, algorithm, algorithmic-trading, trading

I have a trading algo with a fixed period exit. My issue is that I only want to allow the algo to have 1 open position at a time, so we enter the trade at time `t` and exit at say time `t+4` and ignore any trade signals from `t + 1:3`.  At the moment I have a column *Long_Trade* with entry signals and would like it to look like *Signals* as per below:

| Long_Trade | Signal |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |

The code for Long_Trade is:

Long_Trade = np.where(( Long_Sentiment <= 50 ), 1, 0)

Given this criteria, Long_Trade can show 1 for quite some time, but I am only interested in entering one Long_Trade at a time. In its current state, my code will take on all Long_Trades for all instances of 1.

Long_Price_Entry = np.where(( Long_Trade == 1 ), Price , 0)

Long_Price_Exit = np.where(( Long_Trade ==1 ),  Price.shift( -4) , 0)

Could someone please show me how to write a function to create column "Signal" above that will filter Long_Trades so that after the first instance of 1 is seen, the algorithm will not recognise another Long_Trade until 4 periods have passed.
Thanks

Comment: How exactly is this question related to Python? Also, there is a complete lack of detail as to the context as to the meaning of "allow only one algo trade at a time" or what "algo" is being discussed.

Comment: This sounds like a job for binary semaphore

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I thought the context was quite explicit in that a trade is held for a fixed period, and after a trade signal has been generated I only wish to have one trade open during that fixed period.  As per python...the code so far is written in python.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? Do you expect someone to fix the code that you didn't show? Or explain some algorithm? What is the question exactly?